# On link click show post content in div on same page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

**Update:** 
The first item doesn't work. I know java counts from 0 till X.

I used Erik's code and all other links now do what I want them to do. But not the first one. Code now looks like this:

```
$links[] =  '<nav><a href="#' . $num++ . '">' . $term->name . '</a></nav>';
```

Even if I set $num=1 it doesn't register with the first items... on both sides, so the link on the left and the content on the right...

Oh and is there away to give this a `return false` so the #1 won't show in the top URL?

**Original Question**

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

I have this overview page set up in wordpress with my own theme. In this page I list some custom post types, all of them have a post (so there is content and stuff).

The list of custom post types are all links to the post pages of these CPT's. This all works as it should.

But, what I am trying to do is have these links open in a div on the right side of the same page. And have them show up when a user clicks on the corresponding link.

I have tried it using tooltips but this didn't give me the content of the post and the thumbnail.

The links for the CPT's are created in the category-template.php from wordpress it self. I edited the links like this:

```
$links[] = '<a class="various" title="' . $term->name . '<br>' . $id . '" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag">' . $term->name . '</a>';
```

right now it opens a fancybox for these links but I don't want to have all the CPT's open in a fancebox. So this is not an option for me.

Javascript or php? Anyone...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, what I am trying to do is have these links open in a div on the right side of the same page. And have them show up when a user clicks on the corresponding link.

Isn't it a option to load those all those links already when you load the page? So once the page is loaded, you hide the div links you don't want to show by default, with css for example.

And when a user clicks on the corresponding link, you can show the links in the div. In that case you don't have to do any AJAX calls or whatever. You could do this with javaScript:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    $('#div_links').show(500);
});
```

If I understand your question clearly.

http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/EwNRJ/

Comment: Well, this could work. But how will the dynamic links work? How does this go about then.. how do these links know when to hide or when to show...  or is this class based?

Comment: So, have have loaded all the content from the CPT in de div i want the content to be shown. No how do i get them to appear and disappear on clicks when clicking on the corresponding link..

Comment: You could do that by classes, or better, you could use anchor texts. Guess this is exactly what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/4rfYB/2/